# Auto sent and push notification from telegram bot to user by username using nodejs

Tags: bots, telegram-bot

I am using telegram bot by telegraf library and nodejs, but i do not know how to auto (for alert or schedule) sent a message from bot to user by @username. Anybody help me?

Comment: i sloved this problem!

Comment: Would be great if you posted a solution in the naswer.